# Sorting & Unique Records in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable  like

```
public DataTable functiongettable()
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name1");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name5");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name6");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name3");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name3");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name6");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name3");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name5");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name5");

        return dt;
}
```

By using linq query I want to perform Sorting and need unique records.

I am doing like this

```
var query = from c in functiongettable().AsEnumerable().OrderBy("Name").Distinct() select c;
```

But getting error:

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the **DataRowComparer.Default** in the **Distinct** statement.

**UPDATE:**

And use row.Field("Name") when sorting

**UPDATE again:**

```
var query = (from c in functiongettable().AsEnumerable()
            orderby c.Field<string>("Name")
            select c).Distinc(DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a delegate to [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), not a `string`.

Try this:

```
        var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(dr => dr.ItemArray[0] as string)
            .Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default).Select(dr => dr.ItemArray[0]);

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass String as the parameter in OrderBy(). You need to pass in the identity function like so:

```
functiongettable().AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x=>x.Field<string>("Name")).Distinct()
```

And I don't think you will get distinct results here, as the method Distinct() will use the default equality operator of the `TSource`, which in this case will be of the `DataRow`. It will not distinctively select based on the `string` value of your `Name` column.